# Install php5.4 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: php, 19.04

I'm trying to install php5.4 on Ubuntu 19.04, I tried with ondrej's PPA but it no longer has php5.4, only up to php5.6.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.4 is [not supported anymore](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

You can install PHP [from source](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.4) but isn't recommended either, if you really need to use this specific PHP version the easiest way is to install Ubuntu 13.10 or lower

Comment: This is correct until the suggestion to use unsupported EoL releases. There's absolutely no reason for that and any EoL release is off-topic here.

Comment: Have you seriously considered why 5.4, probably time for a later version.

Comment: Giant legacy systems are hard to migrate to newer versions if the development team is not big enough or if the administration decides to keep the old systems. It's a terrible practice but sometimes needs to be done.